# SelectArrayInput with dynamic array data

Tags: admin-on-rest

The SelectArrayInput component in the tutorial used a const array as choices prop, I want to use a dynamic array data which query from server to set to choices prop, can you suggest a solution to me?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if your choices were actually a resource so you can use the `ReferenceArrayInput`. Even if you don't want to allow the user to edit them (with List, Show, etc), you can simply declare a resource like this:

```
<Resource name="choices_resource_name" />
```

This way, you can use it in Reference inputs and fields.

If you can't make it a resource, you'll have to implement a custom input component doing the fetch in a `componentDidMount`, etc.